# How to authenticate with 3rd party services using a popup window?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, popup

While trying to authenticate with Google, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc. I ran into a problem. The authentication needs to be done in a popup window (the client requested it) but after I open the popup I lose control over it and can't communicate back to the main window that the authorization was done.

Here is what happens in detail:

1. User clicks a "Login with Google" button in the main window.
2. The main window opens a popup window to a passport route I am hosting, using `var popup = window.open('http://example.com/login/google')`.
3. If the user has not approved my site to access their account, the URL of the popup changes automatically to something like `http://google.com/OAuth2/`. This redirection is done by the passport component I am using (`koa-passport`).
4. The user approves the login and the URL of the popup is redirected to `http://example.com/login/google/callback` with the authorization token in it. This is where my passport callback route registers the user in my database and creates the authorization token.

The problem is that at this point the user has both the main window and the popup window open and I have no way of notifying the main window that the popup finished the authentication. The popup needs to close automatically and the main window needs to take the user to their private home page.

I tried creating a global function in the main window, but after the final redirection the popup doesn't have access to its parent's global window object. I thought about sending a message from the main window to the popup window to share a global context between them, but the problem with this is that the popup redirects to Google (or some other auth provider) and by the time it redirects back to my callback URL it forgets this context.

The only way I found was to set a timer in the main window and monitor the popup's URL, but that looks like an awful hack. Is there some other way the popup can notify the main window that the user has logged in?